# TOML how to have key without value

Tags: toml, pyproject.toml

Many Python tools these days are using `pyproject.toml` as a config file, and mirror the tool's command line arguments with config file keys.  Tools may have command line flags that are not passed any arguments:

```bash
sometool --some-flag
```

Now, I am trying to place this `--some-flag` into a `pyproject.toml` config file and can't figure out how to have a key without any value.

```ini
[tool.sometool]
# Both of the below are invalid
some-flag
some-flag =
```

In TOML, is it possible to have a key without a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.

It'd depend on the tool how they are doing this, so please refer to their documentation. I would guess they are treating those flags as a boolean.

```ini
[tool.sometool]
some-flag = true
```